Limitations of のに for "purpose/in order to" meanings
I'm confused by this passage from A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar:

Noni is similar in its meaning to Vinf•nonpast tame ni ‘in order to’.
The latter purely means ‘purpose’ but the former retains the meaning
of ‘in the process of’, even when it means ‘purpose’. Thus, in a
sentence such as [4a] below in which the verb in the noni-clause is
incongruous with the meaning of ‘ process ’, noni cannot be used.
[4a] 生きるために/*のに食べる。
(We eat in order to live.)
[4b] この町で生きていくために/のに月二十万円は必要だ。
(We need 200,000 yen a month in order to keep living in this town.)

How would I know if a verb is incongruous with "process"? Would ていく/てきた (suggesting continuation) always allow のに to be used? The verb used here is 生きる, which is nonvolitional isn't it? The dictionary states that only volitional verbs are allowed to precede this type of のに. So I'm confused by its explanation.

According to all the grammar texts I have consulted, のに is the suitable  助詞 for a purpose clause provided the main clause expresses: 1) necessity, with such verbs as “it takes/かかる” ;“need/入る”; “to be necessary 必要だ” 2) usage, with verbs like “to use or be used/使う/使われる”; “to utilize/用いる”.
3) utility, with verbal phrases like “to be useful/役に立つ-便利だ.
All the verbs in the purpose clause cannot but be volitional and all the verbs in the main clause end up to be non-volitional, in any language, due to the intrinsec meaning of these kind of sentences.
So your second sentence rightly belongs in here!
“この町で生きていくために/のに月二十万円は必要だ.”
The first sentence does not though …
And according to common usage, ためにwould be the better solution.
However, we might as well guess that even though no explicit words of necessity or utility occur, it is indeed very true that the overall sense of the sentence calls itself  for an implicit state of need (need of eating in order to survive). Moreover, according to S. Martin, in written and literary Japanese, のに (and even plain に/には) had a  broader meaning, embracing all the senses of a purpose clause, not restricted to necessity situations,  eventually being perfect synonym of ために.

In those cases, the verbs themselves just take a nominal argument in “〜に” and “〜の” just serves to nominalize a clause though. This is not “〜のに” but simply that “私にあなたが必要だ” means “I need you.” and thus also “生きるのに食べるのが必要だ。” means “One needs to eat in order to live.” it's like saying “〜のが”  would express being needed, but that's just a function of “必要” marking the object of necessity with “〜が”. We can also for instance say “死んだのに気づいた。” because “気づく” marks what one notices with “〜に”
